# How to change a field inside a retrofit body request?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit (Im new to it) and gson to serialize an object into a json to send through an api (POST). The object has a date field, and when serializing it, it is not recognized by the api, which responds with:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","birth_date"],"msg":"invalid date format","type":"value_error.date"}]}
```

My class:

```
data class User(
    var name: String = "",
    var email: String = "",
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    var sex: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("birth_date")
    var birthDate: Date = Date()
)
```

My call to the API:

```
@POST("user/me")
    suspend fun createUser(@Header(AUTH_HEADER) token: String, @Body user: User): Response<User>
```

By the API documentation, the date format should be:

```
 "birth_date": "2022-12-22"
```

How can i change the value of birthDate to match the api format on the request body?

Comment: I think your is issue is with date format. In backend using some format which is not match in android side (Date()). And SerializedName is enough and parameter wise all perfect.

Comment: @Dev007, but how can i change the value of birthDate on the request to match the format on the api?

Comment: change Date to String. As you can see "birth_date": "2022-12-22", the value is inside double quote which means String. So, change Date to String, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see

```
"birth_date": "2022-12-22"
```

above date value is in String format.
try by changing the data type Date to String

```
data class User(
    ....
    @SerializedName("birth_date")
    var birthDate: String = ""
)
```

Hope it will work :)